# Display html element after v-for loop was finished

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I have object with elements and I use **v-for** loop to dispaly them on page:

```
    <template v-for="(item, index) in myObject">
      <v-row :key="index">
          <v-col>
            <v-text-field
              v-model="item.value"
              :label="item.name"
            />
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
    </template>
 
    <!-- additional TextField -->
    <v-row>
      <v-col>
        <v-text-field
          v-model="modifyDateTime"
          label="Modify date and time"
        />
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
```

It works fine, but I added additional **v-text-field** below after **v-for** block and it shows up earlier than elements in **v-for** loop rendered.

How can I solve this problem? I need to display the last **v-text-field** element right after elements **v-for** loop was rendered

Comment: wrap both in a `<div v-if="myObject.length">`

Comment: **DO NOT** use index as `:key` ...especially together with any input element....

Comment: @MichalLevý why?

Comment: Because using `index` as `key` is same as not using `key` [at all](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/list.html#maintaining-state)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use v-if in loop

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in myObject">
          <v-row :key="index">
              <v-col>
                <v-text-field
                  v-model="item.value"
                  :label="item.name"
                />
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
            <!-- additional TextField -->

                <v-row v-if="index == Object.keys(item).length - 1">
                  <v-col>
                    <v-text-field
                      v-model="modifyDateTime"
                      label="Modify date and time"
                    />
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
        </template>
```

Comment: This is good idea but why are you checking `item` in `Object.keys(item).length - 1`? I think you should be checking `Object.keys(myObject).length - 1`